# Await for completion redux-saga in react class component method

Tags: reactjs, async-await, fetch, redux-saga

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I've searched for this question, and haven't found an answer that completely gives the solution for my issue. I want to fetch data in sagas and update `localStorage` after data is fetched. Then I want to `this.forceUpdate()` in my component method. But obviously `this.forceUpdate()` function is launched before data 
is loaded. Can I wrap my `handleSubmit` class method into promise or async/await to make my `this.forceUpdate()` await for data to be fetched? Thank you.

**`FETCHING FUNCTION`**

```
export const fetchAuth = data => {
    return axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "http://url/",
        headers: {},
        data: {
            email: data.email,
            password: data.password.toString()
        }
    }).then(response => {
        return response.data;
    });
};
```

**`REDUX-SAGA`**

```
export function* authRequestFlow(action) {
    try {
        const tokens = yield call(fetchAuth, action.payload);
        if (tokens) {
            yield call(save, "access", tokens.access);
            yield call(save, "refresh", tokens.refresh);
            yield call(save, "isAuthorized", true);
            yield put(authSuccess());
        }
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(authFailure(error.message));
    }
}
```

**`COMPONENT`**

```
class Login extends PureComponent {
    handleSubmit = () => {
        authRequest();
        this.forceUpdate();
    };

    render() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("isAuthorized") === "true")
            return <Redirect to="/products" />;
        return (
            <div className={styles.root}>
                    <Button
                        onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                    >
                        Submit
                    </Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly, no - `authRequest()` is just a regular `redux` action which could for example trigger multiple different sagas, so there's no real way to wait for that action to be "done" per se. Instead of using `localStorage` I would recommend storing `isAuthorized` and your auth token in your redux store, connecting your `Login` component to the store and then checking `this.props.auth.isAuthorized` (or whatever your store structure ends up being) instead of relying on `localStorage`. This removes the need for a `forceUpdate` altogether.

Comment: Thank you! it was the great suggestion to move isAuthorized into redux store, i had changed structure of store, and completed my tasks